# How to round off to the nearest month in Excel?

Tags: excel, date

I want to round up today's date to the nearest month. I used Today() to get the current date

I used the formula =MONTH(EOMONTH(L2,DAY(L2)>15)+0)) but it keeps showing an error saying "There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is an equal or minus sign, excel thinks its a formula"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun,
You're just missing a parenthesis in there. Give this a try:

```
=MONTH(EOMONTH(L2,(DAY(L2)>15)+0))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! thank you for answering! But for some reason it still displays the error? Not sure why

Comment: 1. What version of Excel are you using? 2. You're not entering that formula in cell L2 are you?

Comment: 2016 version and also i the tutorial I'm following, it is not showing the day and year?

Comment: Right, for the full date eg. MM/dd/yyyy, you would use `=MONTH(EOMONTH(L2,(DAY(L2)>15)+0)) & "/" & DAY(L2) &"/" & YEAR(L2)`

Comment: oh okay! thanks! I used your formula but whenever its december and rounds up to january, the year does not update and remains the previous year

Comment: Okay, a much longer formula, but this one will solve that last problem: `=DATE(IF(MONTH(EOMONTH(L2,(DAY(L2)>15)+0))<MONTH(L2),YEAR(L2)+1,YEAR(L2)),MONTH(EOMONTH(L2,(DAY(L2)>15)+0)),DAY(L2))`

Answer (score 1):

This formula should do the job.

```
=IFERROR(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+IF(DAY(A1)>15,1,0),1),"")
```

For today (May 7) it will return May 1. To make it return the end of the month, replace the final `1` in the formula with `0`. That would return April 30 today. You can replace all references to cell `A1` with `TODAY()`.